# Writing values to datetime field in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have to create a calendar event through button function.

```
meeting_start_val = datetime.strptime(str_start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
meeting_start = meeting_start_val.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
meeting_end_val = meeting_start_val + timedelta(minutes=60)
meeting_end = meeting_end_val.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print "\n\n\n\n\nn\+++++++++++",meeting_end_val,type(meeting_end_val)
print "\n\n\n\n\nn\+++++++++++",meeting_start_val,type(meeting_start_val)
values = {
'name' : self.contact_name or '/',
'partner_ids' : [(6, 0, x)],
'allday' : False,
'start_datetime' : meeting_start_val,
'stop_datetime': meeting_end_val,
'description' : self.lead_id.name
}
print "\n\n\nn\n\n\n++++++++++++++++++values",values
event.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
```

On executing the above code, I am getting on the print statement

```
1. print "\n\n\n\n\nn\+++++++++++",meeting_end_val,type(meeting_end_val)
```

Answer

```
n\+++++++++++ 2017-09-03 09:00:00 <type 'datetime.datetime'>

2. print "\n\n\n\n\nn\+++++++++++",meeting_start_val,type(meeting_start_val)
```

Answer

```
n\+++++++++++ 2017-09-03 08:00:00 <type 'datetime.datetime'>


3.     print "\n\n\nn\n\n\n++++++++++++++++++values",values
```

Answer

++++++++++++++++++values `{'start_datetime': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 3, 8, 0), 'allday': False, 'description': u'SAC/M/08/17/011', 'stop_datetime': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 3, 9, 0), 'partner_ids': [(6, 0, [2202, 172, 174, 169, 179, 175])], 'name': u'Child Name    '}`

I am facing this issue

```
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

When I am passing as string , it doesnot get error but the time created in the caledar event is wrong.

Any help on this!

Comment: That's right, you should send the dates as objects. Is that your question?

Comment: Yes... thats correct. My question was while writing the datetime field, what to send string or datetime object.

Comment: OK, I see you solved your own question. Next time try to write the question with less noise hahah. Take into account that whatever you use as argument in the function `timedelta` is converted to seconds inside, so it does not matter if you use hours, minutes or days.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ist_timedelta = timedelta(seconds=((self.planned_hours*3600)-10800))
    str_start_time = '%s %s' % (start_time,'00:00:00')
    meeting_start_val = datetime.strptime(str_start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + ist_timedelta
    meeting_start = meeting_start_val.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
    meeting_end_val = meeting_start_val + timedelta(minutes=60)
    meeting_end = meeting_end_val.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    values = {
    'name' : self.contact_name or '/',
    'partner_ids' : [(6, 0, x)],
    'allday' : False,
    'start_datetime' : meeting_start,
    'stop_datetime': meeting_end,
    'description' : self.lead_id.name
    }
    event.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
```

It worked by this..

```
ist_timedelta = timedelta(seconds=((self.planned_hours*3600)-10800))
```

10800 is seconds which is 3 hours, the difference between utc and KSA time. The reason was this conversion.

**__getitem__** error was due to wrong sending of the values in datetime field.